# AngularJS 1.5- ui-router: calling a component inside of a state, with a parent not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, components

I'm using angularJs 1.5. The problem I have is when I call an state with a component, dont work. Dont load the TemplateURL.
I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the call to the state:

```
<a ui-sref="detail-cycle.questionary" ></a>
```

Here the state:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(appConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function appConfig($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('detail-cycle.questionary', {
      url: '/questionary',
      component: "questionary"

    });
}
```

And here the component that dont load:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('questionary', {
      templateUrl: 'app/questionary/questionary.html',
      controller: function ($log) {
        // var vm = this;
        $log.debug("questionary");
      }
    });
})();
```

Any idea??

Thanks!!

Comment: which ui-router version you are using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using 1.0.0-beta.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the component attribute for UI router you can also just directly call the component in the template for the state.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(appConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function appConfig($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('detail-cycle.questionary', {
      url: '/questionary',
      template: <questionary></questionary>

    });
}
```

Comment: Hi! It didnt work. I have the same problem, "questionary" component is not loading.